# Was a Lwaxana Troi sitcom actually planned?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, gene-roddenberry

A few years ago, I found the following claim on a random blog: at one point during the early *TNG* years, Gene Roddenberry had proposed a "Lwaxana Troi sitcom", starring his wife Majel Barrett-Roddenberry (who played Lwaxana Troi in several *TNG*-era Star Trek episodes).

**Is there an official source confirming that this was really proposed by Roddenberry?  If so, was this intended to be a half-hour-format sitcom with a laugh track, as was the norm at that time for comedic television series?**

Comment: I sense amusement!!

Comment: From what I can tell it was one of a wide range of ideas mooted by Gene Roddenberry. I suspect it never got past the "one line" stage; http://www.warpedfactor.com/2014/11/5-bizarre-proposed-star-trek-episodes.html

Comment: It's mentioned in Starlog; https://archive.org/stream/starlog_magazine-177/177_djvu.txt

Comment: Some of these [Undeveloped Star Trek projects](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Undeveloped_Star_Trek_projects) look  truly awful.

Comment: Dear god, I hope not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Maybe.

The earliest mention of a "Lwaxana Troi sitcom" seems like it was in [Starlog #177](https://archive.org/stream/starlog_magazine-177/177_djvu.txt), April 1992. *(Thanks to @Richard for [mentioning this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107482/was-a-lwaxana-troi-sitcom-actually-planned#comment253048_107482))*, Most mentions of it don't provide any source at all, and the ones that do tend to point to Starlog #177, the exact quote being:

> A fourth possibility — a SF sitcom starring Majel Barrett as
> Lwaxana Troi — had been mulled by Barrett, Gene Roddenberry  and The
> Sci-Fi Channel as a project for  that cable network. But Roddenberry's
> death and SFC's start-up delays have sidelined that idea for now.

The most "reliable" sources, aside from that fleeting mention in Starlog I can find are mostly Top 10 lists, fan blogs and the like. I haven't found any sort of documents, or anything "official" suggesting they really did consider it.

Comment: @Richard, yeah, that's this question!

Comment: @Richard Sorry, forgot to mention that, is it better now? Thanks.

Comment: @SpaceIsBig42 - Much better :-)

Comment: They say there are no bad ideas in brainstorming. They are wrong.